# Click Button which is not visible on IRCTC, using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

The `book now` button on Irctc is not clickable.
The error shown is element not interactable.
I tried using

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("")));
```

But still no gain.

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"); //This is the location where you have installed Firefox on your machine

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.get("http://www.irctc.co.in");//It will open the website

driver.manage().window().maximize();//It will maximize the window

Thread.sleep(5000);//For Entering the Captcha before 5sec

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='usernameId']")).sendKeys("");//enter username

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='loginPassword']")).sendKeys("");//enter password

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='loginbutton']")).click();//clicks on sign in

Thread.sleep(2000);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='jpform:fromStation']")).sendKeys("H NIZAMUDDIN - NZM");//origin station


driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='jpform:toStation']")).sendKeys("KOTA JN - KOTA");//destination station


driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='jpform:journeyDateInputDate']")).sendKeys("18-05-2017");//Date Of Journey

Thread.sleep(2000);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='jpform:jpsubmit']")).click();//Clicks to find the trains

Thread.sleep(2000);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='cllink-13237-CC-1']")).click();//Clicks the class of train to find available seats

Thread.sleep(5000);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='13237-3A-GN-0']")).click();//For clicking on Book Now, but is not functioning.
```

Comment: no element with id `cllink-13237-CC-1` exists on the page. Which train did you intend to select ?

Comment: The train number I have mentioned in the code is wrong. Otherwise that line of code was executing successfully in Firefox Browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** **I am not encouraging the automation of IRCTC. This is just to guide the OP in the right direction. Use at your own risk.**

I am using `ChromeDriver`, you can use any driver, but make sure it supports `Javascript`. Here is the code

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

class Main{
    public static void main(String args[])throws InterruptedException{
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Shash\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("window-size=1024,768");

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);

        driver.get("http://www.irctc.co.in");//It will open the website
        Thread.sleep(5000);//For Entering the Captcha before 5sec

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='usernameId']")).sendKeys("");//enter username

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='loginPassword']")).sendKeys("");//enter password

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='loginbutton']")).click();//clicks on sign in

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='jpform:fromStation']")).sendKeys("H NIZAMUDDIN - NZM");//origin station


        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='jpform:toStation']")).sendKeys("KOTA JN - KOTA");//destination station


        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='jpform:journeyDateInputDate']")).sendKeys("18-05-2017");//Date Of Journey

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='jpform:jpsubmit']")).click();//Clicks to find the trains
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='cllink-12060-CC-0']")).click();//Clicks the class of train to find available seats
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
            ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
                .executeScript("document.getElementById(\"12060-CC-GN-0\").click()");
        }
    }
}
```

Your code had several problems. First, an element with the ID `cllink-13237-CC-1` did not exist. Make sure you get the exact ID of the element. As IRCTC doesn't allow right-clicking, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to view the source.

Secondly, the `Book Now` element was hidden, therefore I used `Javascript` to click on it.

Comment: Thanks for the solution,It is working fine now.  Can you suggest where should I give waits and where should I avoid it.

Comment: @SushantKumar you can remove all `Thread.sleep`. Just keep it for the captcha and Before the JavaScript Executor. You may have to experiment again, as I am not that familiar with IRCTC.